# How to build console based and window less AIR application using flex 4

Tags: unix, flex4, air

I created and AIR application using Flex4. It has a window showing nothing. If I install my AIR application and run it, no application UI window should be displayed. that means I need to build a window less AIR application. It is required because, I need to run this application in console based UNIX server. UNIX server is throwing an error "Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display." when this application is trying to be executed. Please help me out to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't solve this on the AIR side. AIR is designed to run with windows. Developers have reported success using Xvfb virtual framebuffer: http://groups.google.com/group/fluint-discussions/browse_thread/thread/b4be801162a00dfc?pli=1

Comment: pls have a look into this following link: http://agoln.net/archives/106. is it possible to do this one?

Comment: It looks like he is just launching the unzipped app with the AIR Debug Launcher (ADL) utility. That should work to start an app, but has no bearing on the question above. The apps will still need windows.